# Printing to paper not showing bound data in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, printdialog

I was trying to take print of a WPF view in that I was using PrintVisual from PrintDialog class. Using this my binding was not working when I was taking print to a paper printer. But it was showing correctly while printed to pdf converter or OneNote. any idea why this happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer It was because I was doing measure override and arrange override for the UI element. But UI was not updating. So I have added UpdateLayout method call and problem is solved.